# Remove elements from collection

Tags: java, collections

What I want to do is remove all elements in a collection that are less than a specified object. This is what I have:

```
static void removeAllLessThan(Collection c, Object x) {
    for(Object a : c) if(a.compareTo(x) < 0) c.remove(a);
}
```

This does not work because Object has no compareTo method. What I want to know is how should I compare between objects? Also what is the natural comparator? Thank you.

Comment: `c` is a collection of Objects ?

Comment: Any reason why you don't use a class that implements `compareTo` instead of `Object`?

Comment: Because I want this to work for any object

Comment: Which type of collection is this and what all values are you going to store in that?

Comment: any random type of object can not be compared in generic way, you need different logic for comparing different type of objects.

Comment: comparing two different object never can be true unless they both have compareTo and they compare certain value inside the object which should be equal. But also if objects dosn't know about the type of each others this  will not work. As you still need somthing inside the object you need to compare with, and in your case this will never happend.

Comment: You stated it yourself: `This does not work because Object has no compareTo method`. You need the method to take a `Collection<Comparable>`.

Comment: using Collection<Comparable> instead of Collection,and implement Comparable to all your items in the collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `Collection<Comparable>` instead of `Collection`,and implement `Comparable` to all your items in the collection. And change your method like:

```
static void removeAllLessThan(Collection<Comparable> c, Comparable x) {
    for (Iterator<Comparable> it = c.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
        if (it.next().compareTo(x) < 0)
            it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by using generics, and let the caller declare what type of object he wants to filter by:

```
static <T> void removeAllLessThan(Collection<T> collection, T t) {...}
```

This isn't enough, however.  You need to use a `Comparator<T>` to provide the ordering.

```
static <T> void removeAllLessThan(Collection<T> collection,
                                  Comparator<T> comparator, T t) {...}
```

Then, allow the user some flexibility when working with inheritance.  He has to do the equivalent of `t1 < t2`, but the comparator can be of any supertype of T, and the collection can be of anything that extends T:

```
static <T> void removeAllLessThan(Collection<? extends T> collection,
                                  Comparator<? super T> comparator, T t) {...}
```

Then, there is a mistake with the deletion process. The only mechanism that can delete from a collection while iterating over it is the `Iterator`. Anything else risks a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

```
static <T> void removeAllLessThan(Iterable<? extends T> iterable,
                                  Comparator<? super T> comparator, T t) {
    for (Iterator<? extends T> it = iterable.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        if (comparator.compare(it.next(), t) < 0) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Note the signature change.

Finally, this is a very specific method. You will need to write lots of nearly identical methods like removeIfGreaterThan, removeIfEqualIgnoringCase, etc.  Write a generic `removeIf` method, with signature

```
public <T> removeIf(Iterable<? extends T> iterable,
                    Predicate<? super T> predicate){...}
```

`Predicate` is an interface provided by lots of libraries that has just a boolean `eval` method.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this problem.

First, you can use `Comparable` Interface, which means that the method should be changed into:

```
static void removeAllLessThan(Collection<Comparable> c, Comparable x) {
    for(Comparable a : c) if(a.compareTo(x) < 0) c.remove(a);
}
```

An object should be comparable to have a method called `comparedTo`.

Second, you can implement a `Comparator` to judge which is bigger. If you don't want the object to be comparable, which means you don't want to change the existing code to let it implement `Comparable`, this is a better way. But the code will be change into:

```
static void removeAllLessThan(Collection c, Object x, Comparator comp) {
    for(Object a : c) if(comp(a, x) < 0) c.remove(a);
}
```

Here is the javadoc of [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).